# Wrapping textarea as a React component and exposing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have wrapped a `<textarea />` tag as a react component which sits inside of an Ant Design Form.Item like so:

```js
<Form.Item
  name="query"
  label="Query"
>
  <CodeEditor />
</Form.Item>
```

the issue is that when I submit the form, the value for "query" is undefined.

If I replace `<CodeEditor />` with the text area code like so:

```js
<Form.Item
  name="query"
  label="Query"
>
  <textarea />
</Form.Item>
```

the "query" value is set correctly.

How should one wrap form tags in React so that their native props/functions are exposed? I would expect refs to work here but I assume there is a better approach.

**EDIT**

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-buck-rbvc9?file=/src/App.js). If you enter some text into the CodeEditor input and click the "Console Log Query" button, "undefined" will be logged. But if you replace  on line 22 with `<textarea />` the query value will be logged.

Comment: could you please show props of CodeEditor component?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at least the code of the `CodeEditor` component

Comment: Provided a CodeSandbox example. @slideshowp2

Comment: @Oro any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use custom component as a children of `Form.Item` you should provide `value` and `onChange` props to it, because Form.Item will use them for changing the Form Instance.

In your case the code of CodeEditor component will look like this:

```
function CodeEditor({ value, options, readOnly, onChange }) {
  const textRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <Editor
      value={value}
      ref={textRef}
      language="sql"
      placeholder="Please enter SQL code."
      onChange={onChange}
      padding={15}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
        fontFamily:
          "ui-monospace,SFMono-Regular,SF Mono,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,monospace",
        fontSize: 16
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-leftpad-m44i3?file=/src/components/CodeEditor.js)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead os using:

```
 <Form.Item
   name="query"
   label="Query"
 >
    <textarea />
 </Form.Item>
```

You can try this component imported from antd as shown below:

```
import { Input } from 'antd';

const { TextArea } = Input;

<Form.Item
  name="query"
  label="Query"
>
  <TextArea />
</Form.Item>
```